# Bootstrap span are not inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

JSfiddle of my code http://jsfiddle.net/55PqG/6/

Why button1 and button2 are not standing side by side?

```
<div class="row-fluid span12" style="width: 300px">
    <div class="row-fluid span6 " style="background-color: #ff0;">button1</div>
    <div class="row-fluid span6  btn" style="background-color: #f0f;">button2</div>
</div>
```

And does span work differently with tables in bootstrap? (code is in JSFiddle)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `row-fluid` from both buttons. Also the first button needs the `.btn` class

```
<div class="span6 btn" style="background-color: #ff0;">button1</div>
<div class="span6  btn" style="background-color: #f0f;">button2</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/55PqG/7/

Comment: It still doesn't stay side by side.

Comment: If your using a fluid layout it all depends on the size of the container.  If you expand that fiddle window they will go side by side.  Are you specifying `.container-fluid` on a container in the markup?  If you want to just force the `span` classes from the buttons. http://jsfiddle.net/55PqG/8/

Comment: Actually I'm trying to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/ySW2G/8/. There will be some content, which will use span* classes, inside a table cell. And this code also will be inserted into some part of page which is inside the container. **But it seems span* classes doesn't work properly inside a table cell.** I really need to use span inside divs inside table cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can give float to one of the container div of buttons, so ur code will be like

```
<div class="row-fluid span12" style="width: 300px">
<div class="row-fluid span6 " style="background-color: #ff0;float:left;">button1</div>
<div class="row-fluid span6  btn" style="background-color: #f0f;">button2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSFiddle won't work because

1. You're missing the bootstrap.js file - which is necessary
2. Your bootstrap.css file isn't attached properly

Consider reading this http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem on Bootstrap's fluid grid system.
The code you want is something like this

```
<div class="row-fluid span12"> <!-- No specification of width, leave that to span12 -->
    <div class="span6 btn">button1</div> <!-- No row-fluid here -->
    <div class="span6 btn">button2</div>
</div>
```

That said, I'm not sure why you're creating buttons using divs. Also consider reading this http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons on Bootstrap's button functionality.

This would make your code closer to

```
<div class="row-fluid span12">
    <button type="button" class="btn span6">button1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn span6">button2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Stephen. This div will be inside a table cell, and inside of two divs will be some code, buttons just to find out the error. I thought it's wrong with div. But if it's ok, than it seems like span* doesn't working properly inside the table cell. My actual code jsfiddle.net/ySW2G/8